# SQL Query Except then select TOP 10

Tags: sql, sql-server, except

I have the following query where I EXCEPT two results in Microsoft SQL Server

```
SELECT *
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (1)

EXCEPT

SELECT *
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (2)

ORDER BY News.PublishDate DESC
```

The result has lots of records, but I only want the first 10 results. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Since you select all columns, the EXCEPT wont remove anything. NewsAudience.PortalId  = 1 for first select, and 2 for second select.

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't make sense.  You are getting *all* rows from the first subquery.  Why?  Because you are using `select *` and `NewsAudience.PortalId` is in the select list.  That value is automatically different based on the conditions in the subqueries.

I would recommend phrasing your need differently.  For instance, you might intend:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM News n
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM NewsAssignment na JOIN
                   NewsAudience nau
                   ON na.NewsAudienceId = nau.Id AND na.PortalId IN (1)
              WHERE n.Id = na.NewsId
             ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM NewsAssignment na JOIN
                       NewsAudience nau
                       ON na.NewsAudienceId = nau.Id AND na.PortalId IN (2)
                  WHERE n.Id = na.NewsId
                 )
ORDER BY n.PublishDate DESC;
```

You can add `TOP (10)` to the outer query if duplicates are still a problem after you have correct the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT`:

```
Select *
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (1)
ORDER BY News.PublishDate DESC

EXCEPT

SELECT *
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (2)
ORDER BY News.PublishDate DESC
)a
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I tried something like that but I get an error at "a" The column "CustomerId" was specified multiple times for "a"

Comment: But the inner query runs fine?

Comment: @FerronSW - you need to remove `*` and list columns explicitly (good habit to be in anyway). SQL can return *result sets* to a client that contain multiple columns with the same name but balks at allowing such things in subqueries etc. (You at least need to do the two that form the `except`, whether you also do the outer one is a matter of taste)

Answer (score 0):

use `top` keyword as you are using sql server

```
select top 10 t.* from 
(
SELECT *
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (1)

EXCEPT

SELECT *
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (2)
) t order by t.PublishDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever and @Mayank Porwal

```
Select TOP(10) *
FROM
(
SELECT News.Author, News.CreateDate, News.CustomerId, News.EditDate, News.EndDate, News.Id, News.ImageUrl, News.PublishDate, News.Text, News.Title
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (1)

EXCEPT

SELECT News.Author, News.CreateDate, News.CustomerId, News.EditDate, News.EndDate, News.Id, News.ImageUrl, News.PublishDate, News.Text, News.Title
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (2)

) a

ORDER BY a.PublishDate DESC
```

Comment: That's great. But mark the appropriate responses as answers since that how SO is designed to work - questions are asked and then **answered** so that others having the same or similar question can find an **answer**.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * from  (SELECT *
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (1)

EXCEPT

SELECT *
FROM News
INNER JOIN NewsAssignment on News.Id = NewsAssignment.NewsId
INNER JOIN NewsAudience on NewsAssignment.NewsAudienceId = NewsAudience.Id
WHERE NewsAudience.PortalId IN (2)

ORDER BY News.PublishDate DESC);
```